# Magento sales_flat_order_item simple and configurable quantities not matched

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm facing a very weird issue with some orders having qty_ordered not matching between configurable and simple products.

I know that for each item in the order, Magento will save 2 rows of records, 1 is configurable and the other is simple with parent_item_id linking to the configurable. Usually the qty_ordered are the same between these 2 rows, but some orders are having those 2 rows not matching up the quantity, which is causing issue with our shipping. Does anyone know at least where to look or debug?

I'm using Magento 1.9

Comment: Have you used any third party extension, please disable and then check.

Comment: Yeah i have a lot of thrid party extensions installed that's why it's quite hard to check, but most of the time everything is correct, only 1-2 orders every 3 months will have this problem